# Spring MVC with RESTful Services and Static HTML

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, wildfly

I am using Java8 with Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE.  I have a project that needs to serve both static html pages and RESTful Services.

I can get one to work at a time, but not both at the same time.

For example, I need to access:

```
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/category/list
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/category/list/{id}
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/index.html
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/tocs.html
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/www/index.html
```

My issue is with regards to my `servlet-mapping`.

I have the following:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        Dynamic rest = servletContext.addServlet("rest", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        //dynamic.addMapping("/**/*.do");
        rest.addMapping("/*.html");
        rest.addMapping("/category/list");
        rest.addMapping("/category/list/*");
        rest.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

I have tried a number of combinations of mappings, but cannot seem to get static content and RESTful services to work simultaneously.

In the above example, I can get the following to work:

```
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/index.html
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/snoop.jsp
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/WebContent/index.html
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/category/list
```

But, the following is not found:

```
http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly-1.0/category/list/AC
```

The following allows the RESTful Services to be accessed, but not the static html files:

```
rest.addMapping("/");
```

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code for one of my RESTful Services:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping(CategoryRESTService.BASE_URI)
public class CategoryRESTService {

    public static final String BASE_URI = "/category";

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Category>> findAllCategorys() {
        List<Category> categories = categoryService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Category>>(categories, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Category> findCategoryById(@PathVariable String id) {
        Category category = categoryService.findById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Category>(category, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: why you're not using @RequestMapping to map the rest calls?

Comment: Can you show a fragment of the controller which maps `category/list/{id}` path?

Comment: Added an UPDATE above with a code sample of my RESTful Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use  `rest.addMapping("/");` mapping, at the same time you have to configure static resource resolver, for example

through xml configuration

```
<mvc:resources mapping="*.html" location="location of the resource folder" />
```

or java-base config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("*.html")
          .addResourceLocations("location of the resource folder"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Melad, thanks for the feedback. I try the following, but it doesn't work (ie. the `index.html` is not found). Perhaps my resource location is incorrect? `registry.addResourceHandler("*.html").addResourceLocations("/webapp/");`. Where my `index.html` is `src/main/webapp/index.html`.

Comment: Fixed, I added this and it finds `index.html`: `addResourceLocations("/");`.  Thank you very much.

Comment: `addResourceLocations("/")` works for the `webapp` directory. But if I have another directory with html files, i.e. `/webapp/www/index.html`, adding another `addResourceLocations("/www/")` does not work.